# Doctrine2 STI: how do you change the descrimnator column value?

Tags: doctrine-orm, typo3-flow

I have  objects that users can buy to use.

Backpacks. Backpacks have different types so I was thinking I would use STI as described in the doctrine docs:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

This is fine, and works. Someone can buy a BasicBackPack, or a LargeBackPack and the correct class is created when the entity is collected from the repository.

This all works fine.

My problem now is, is that I want people to be able to upgrade a BasicBackPack to a LargeBackPack but I find I can't changethe descriminator column value. When ever I try doctrine complains that there is no "descriminatorColumn" in class x, but there is as I can see it in the database.

Is it not possible to change the descrimnator column value once an entity is made?

Comment: Hello, please show the raw error message. How do you try to change the value of the discriminator column?

Comment: I tried creating a getter and setter in my entity model, but if i do that doctrine complains that there is no property called descriminator.
If I then define the property for descriminator doctrine complains that the property already exists (it does, in the DB created by doctrine - does this without any property being defined in my model). It seems like doctrine doesn't want you to be able to change the descriminator value

Comment: Is it due to the fact that you call it _descriminator_?

Comment: Can you try to copy all the properties from BasicBackPack to LargeBackPack? This way you will create the correct entity LargeBackPack.